# Unable to set the value of a textfield before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textfield with name `Ivrmapping[WelcomeNotes]`. I have to update its value by a JSON before submitting the form.

```
JSON format-"welcomenotesList":["Thanks for calling us","Please select from the following list"]"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5QPE/)
But when I try to update the value by its name, I get a different value.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to change the value of the textfield before submitting the form, because in my current scenario even after trying to change the value, the default gets posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no element with an ID of `Ivrmapping[WelcomeNotes]` in your fiddle (that's the name). The ID is `Ivrmapping_WelcomeNotes`. So try either

```
$("#Ivrmapping_WelcomeNotes").val("20");
```

or

```
$("[name='Ivrmapping[WelcomeNotes]']").val("20");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/Nem26/1